# Saving after editting through javascript, and resizing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript:

```
<script>
function showMe(){
document.querySelector('#change').style.display = '';
document.querySelector('#keep').style.display = 'none'
document.querySelector('#change1').style.display = '';
document.querySelector('#keep1').style.display = 'none'
document.querySelector('#change2').style.display = '';
document.querySelector('#keep2').style.display = 'none'
document.querySelector('#change3').style.display = '';
document.querySelector('#keep3').style.display = 'none'
document.querySelector('#change4').style.display = '';
document.querySelector('#keep4').style.display = 'none'
}
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-user-information">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><span id= "keep">Username</span><input id= "change" value= "Name" style= "display:none;"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date of Birth</td>
<td><span id= "keep1">01/24/1988</span><input id= "change1" value= "11/14/2016" style= "display:none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender</td>
<td><span id= "keep2">Female/Male</span><input id= "change2" value= "Female" style= "display:none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td><span id= "keep3">US</span><input id= "change3" value= "US" style= "display:none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><span id= "keep4"><a href="mailto:info@support.com">info@support.com</a></span><input id= "change4" value= "Email" style= "display:none;"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<a data-original-title="Broadcast Message" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
<span class="pull-right">
<a href="#" data-original-title="Edit this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" onclick = 'showMe()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
<a data-original-title="Save this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i></a>
</span>
</div>
```

How can I make the edit save for good once I click on the save button? Also when I click edit, the table gets a bit bigger, I tried changing the font-size to be equal before and after the edit but it didnt work, what seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are padding left `<div id="icons">` with 250px. If you want to center them, you can use `margin: 0 auto;`. Also you can add css for mobile only using `@media` queries ( see more info  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries )

Comment: Ok so I remove the left padding and put margin auto?

Comment: Yes, here is a more detailed answer about centering a div horizontally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Comment: when i removed my padding, my background image was removed and it became with the last one